# getJsonStringFromURL() return a null string

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to get a json string from a url and my method is returning a null string value when I use this line of code:

```
String jsonStr = getJsonStringFromURL(url);
```

Here is the method I'm using:

```
public static String getJsonStringFromURL(String url)  {
    InputStream is = null; 
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    try { 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
        return null;
    }

    try { 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { 
        return null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have a url variable used where when I copy and paste the url into a browser it does return and display a json string.  Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give the url and you are getting exception that return null. Debug your application. On what you os version you are trying.

Comment: The code is probably returning `null` due to an exception. You need to **at least** log the caught exceptions.

Comment: Does your JSON string validate using something like JSONlint? it could be an invalid JSON string if otherwise. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @JakeCataford If its invalid then it can not be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you assigning value to the result when `BufferReader` is closed. Thats why you getting the null value.

Instead of assigning `result = sb.toString()`; outside of the `BufferReader` assign it before closing it.

```
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
        sb.append(line + "\n"); 
    }
    result = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(result);// It will print you the value
    is.close();
```

Hope it helps.